# Uncaught SyntaxError: Illegal break statement in Hangman Game

Tags: javascript, syntax-error, break

I'm coding a Hangman game and I'm getting this error even though I have checked it multiple times and can find no error.
I did read about this on Stack Overflow and could not find a solution for my particular situation. It is not a function so it should be a break and not a return.

My code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="eng">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="review.css">
    <script src="review.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Hangman</h2>    

    <script> 
        // pick our random words for the game & save in an array in a 
        varibale
        var word = [
         "school",
         "teacher", 
         "class", 
         "principal"];

        // use this to pick a random word from the array
        var word = words[Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length)];

        // create an empty array and fill it with underscores to match the number of letters in a word
        var answerArray = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < word.length; i ++) {
            answerArray[i] = "_";
            }
        // variable set to the length of the secret word; use this to keep track of how many letters are left to guess
            var remainingLetters = word.length;

        // we will continue to loop as long as the number of letters is greater than zero; once it is zero they have correctly guessed the word; .join changes an array into a string
            while (remainingLetters > 0) {
            alert(answerArray.join("  "));
            }
        // prompt takes a guess from the player and saves it to the varible guess; now we must handle 4 separate scenarios: the player does not provide a letter, the letter is greater than 1, the player does it correctly
            var guess = prompt("Guess a letter, or click cancel to stop playing.");
        if (guess === null) {
            // exit the game loop
            break;  
        }else if (guess.length !== 1) {
            alert("Please enter a single letter.");

        }else {
            for (var j =0; j < word.length; j++){
                if (word[j] === guess) {
                    answerArray[j] = guess;
                    remainingLetters --;
                }
            }
        }

        alert(answerArray.join(" "));
        alert("Good. The answer was "  + word);

    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: well break needs to be in a loop and I do not see it in a loop so....

Comment: The guess and check code and such probably has to be inside the while-loop, so the user keeps getting prompts until the word is found. Then break would make sense.

Comment: Yes. I see what you all are saying. I just copied it from the book and assumed it would be correct. . .and this is a book for children. . ..disturbing. Anyhow, thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 1):

You have to put your code in While loop.. like this and break; will work coz it is in loop::::)))

```
while (remainingLetters > 0) {
    alert(answerArray.join("  "));

    var guess = prompt("Guess a letter, or click cancel to stop playing.");
    if (guess === null) {
        // exit the game loop
        break;
    } else if (guess.length !== 1) {
        alert("Please enter a single letter.");
    } else {
        for (var j =0; j < word.length; j++){
            if (word[j] === guess) {
                answerArray[j] = guess;
                remainingLetters --;
            }
        }
    }
}

alert(answerArray.join(" "));
alert("Good. The answer was "  + word);
```